# Swift reserved function names?

Tags: function, methods, swift, reserved

Can someone please explain how certain functions get called? Is a function named as init going to be called automatically when someone creates a new object like so: `var object: type = type(param1)`.
I have also seen this in `NSURLConnection`. Methods seem to have names like `connectionDidFinishLoading` or something but I don't understand, is it coded into the swift language for that name to have special actions? Is that function just gonna run as soon the connection finished? Like how would it even know unless you "sent a message" to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first, in Swift, you don't "send messages" to objects anymore. Function and method calls are linked directly together by the compiler. The only except to this is when you have objects that inherit from `NSObject` because then it still runs on the Objective-C runtime.

Second, `type(param1)` is an example of an `init` function. It isn't "automatically" calling it. That is just how you define [initializer methods in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_266). You are directly calling it when creating the object.

Third `connectionDidFinishLoading` is defined on the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. When you create an `NSURLConnection` you can give it a delegate that should implement this protocol. If you have an object set as the delegate that implements the protocol, the `NSURLConnection` instance will call that method when appropriate. That is how the [Delegate Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html) works that is all over UIKit and Cocoa.